# System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations - reference

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm converting a .net core 1.0 project to 2.2 net core

There is a reference to System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations I'm trying to resolve, has this been factored into a seperate nuget package in .net core

```
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'DataAnnotations' does not exist in the  namespace 'System.ComponentModel' (are you  missing an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: Are you referencing `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` or `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All`?

Comment: Thank you, that cleared the error

Answer (score 0):

Adding references to Microsoft.AspNetCore.App and Microsoft.AspNetCore.All cleared the error.